# Some questions about projects in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

**1: When I open VS and start a new project the page that should I type my code in it doesn't appear, as you can see in the picture that I uploaded.**

**2: If you open your browser you can open many tabs like you can open a tab for Google and another for Facebook.... I want to know in VS how can I open many projects at the same time and move among them like I do in the browser.**

Some notes that maybe help : I'm using Windows 10 and my default collection is Visual C++.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVJOW.png]

[Visual Studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVJOW.png)

Comment: ***. I want to know in VS how can I open many projects at the same time and move among them like I do in the browser.*** I have opened solutions in Visual Studio that had 500 projects and 3 million lines of code. My own solutions are typically 20 to 50 projects and 25 to 50 thousand lines of code.

Comment: 2: You can have more than one instance of VS, although that is not quite the same. Two monitors helps.

Comment: There is no tabbed view for projects in a solution. There is a tabbed view for files in a project.

Comment: ***When I open VS and start a new project the page that should I type my code in it doesn't appear,*** When you close your project in Visual Studio it will remember the windows you have open. VS will reopen these same windows when you reopen your project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the **first** problem will be like that :

1. Go to **Solution Explorer**.
2. Then click the right button on the **"Application Name or the Source Files Folder"**
3. Choose **Add** then **New Item** then choose from the page that will appear to you the file you want, "In my problem I will choose **CPP File**".

### [Application Name or the Source Files Folder picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SQpO.png)

The solution for the **second** problem will be like that :

1. Go to **Solution Explorer**.
2. Then click the right button on the "**Solution Name**"
3. Choose **Add** then **New Project**

[Solution Name picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igho2.png)